# Extract text between two words from entire string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string-matching

I have a string where I want to extract all the words that is between two text, such that:

```
var str="This is the number I want +2143334 !, again this is the next number I want +234343443 !, last number I want +76645 !, fininshed";

var ext = str.split('want').pop().split('!,').shift(); 
alert(ext);
```

But this gives only `+2143334`. What I want is all three matching i.e:

```
+2143334, +234343443, +76645
```

How can it be done?

Comment: You’ll probably want to use a regex. How familiar are you with them?

Comment: Do you only want to extract `+` followed with diigts after `want`? Or any non-whitespace chunks?

Comment: @Ryan not much familiar with regex

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to extract + followed with digits after want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the following regex to capture the `+` followed with 1+ digits after `want`:

```
 /want\s*(\+\d+)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/abMDmY/1/).

Here, `want` matches a literal substring, then `\s*` matches 0+ whitespace chars and the `(\+\d+)` captures into Group 1 a plus sign and then 1+ digits.

In Chrome, you may even use `str.match(/(?<=want\s*)\+\d+/g)`, but not all browsers already support the ECMAScript 2018 cool regex features.

[image]

JS demo:

```js
var str="This is the number I want +2143334 !, again this is the next number I want +234343443 !, last number I want +76645 !, fininshed";
var m,results = [];
var rx = /want\s*(\+\d+)/g;
while(m=rx.exec(str)) {
  results.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RegExp [`(?<=want )([^ ]*)(?= !)`](https://regex101.com/r/fx41ht/1) :

`(?<=want )` makes sure `want[space]` is behind your expression

`([^ ]*)` matches anything but a space

`(?= !)` makes sure `[space]!` is after your expression

The `g` is added to make the RegEx **global**.

```js
var str = "This is the number I want +2143334 !, again this is the next number I want +234343443 !, last number I want +76645 !, fininshed";

console.log(str.match(/(?<=want )([^ ]*)(?= !)/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your code is giving +76645 as result. Anyway, the more straigthforward way to do it is as follows:

```js
var str="This is the number I want +2143334 !, again this is the next number I want +234343443 !, last number I want +76645 !, fininshed";

// To extract numbers only
var vetStrings = str.match(/\d+/g);
console.log(vetStrings);

// To cast the result as numbers
var vetNumbers = vetStrings.map(Number);
console.log(vetNumbers);
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
var reg = /(?<=want\s)[a-zA-Z0-9+]+(?=\s\!)/g;
var yourText = 'This is the number I want +2143334 !, again this is the next number I want +234343443 !, last number I want +76645 !, fininshed';
var resultArray = yourText.match(reg);
console.log(resultArray);
```

Where

> want\s

(\s is for space) is text before your match, and

> \s\!

if for text after your match.

Best regards ;)

Comment: Now I've seen @Zenoo answer, I think it's even clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one

```
  str.match(/want\s[a-zA-Z0-9+!@#$%^&*()_+={}|\\]+\s!/g).map((e)=>e.split(' ')[1])
```